# How to remove table name prefix from aspnetboilerplate Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to use `aspnetboilerplate` Core 2 in MVC (not Angular version).

After running *Add-Migration* and *Update-Database*, all of the created tables have `Abp` prefix.
Such as: `AbpUsers`, `AbpRoles`, `AbpFeatures`, ...

How can I remove `Abp` from table names?

I see some instructions but all of them are related to MVC5 version of `aspnetboilerplate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered in this issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2382

> ## For Entity Framework Core
>
> Override `OnModelCreating` and call `modelBuilder.ChangeAbpTablePrefix`. Example:
>
> ```
> protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
> {
>     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
>
>     modelBuilder.ChangeAbpTablePrefix<Tenant, Role, User>(""); // Removes table prefixes. You can specify another prefix.
> }
> ```
>
> Remember to add `using Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore;` to your code file in order to access `ChangeAbpTablePrefix` extension method.

Comment: Where i can append this override? in which class?

Comment: Override in `YourDbContext`.

Comment: after New Migration Worked for me. Tnx a lot.